# Is there a way for registration free activation of EXE COM components

Tags: c#, com, interop, side-by-side, regfreecom

Is there a way to activate a COM component which is an **EXE** COM application and also it's dependent COM dlls? I want to activate this COM component from .NET application(VS 2005/VS 2008).

The path of call is C# application --> invoking out-of-proc exe(this is through COM) and then this out-of-proc invokes few COM dlls

Answer (score 2):

Reg-free COM does not work for out of process components.

> ActiveX EXE and ActiveX Document
>   project types cannot be used with
>   Reg-Free COM, as discussed in the
>   sidebar.

[Simplify App Deployment with ClickOnce and Registration-Free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Look at Microsoft Forum [Registration-Free EXE COM Server ?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/3849f22d-c8b8-429e-a03a-37601411acec)
So, There is no direct way to do this work whithot any additional code. As for me, the code still needs for classic registration to correct date marshaling.

Answer (score 0):

[Registration free activation is described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx). Roughly speaking, it looks like you create your COM components and clients as usual, then put them all into the same directory with a manifest file which contains the COM registration information.

Comment: I had seen this and tried using this for the application. it works for a dll, but not for a exe.as I said the path of call is 
C# application --> invoking out-of-proc exe(this is through COM) and then this out-of-proc invokes few COM dlls.

Comment: oh sorry, I don't think that registration free COM activation really supports DCOM

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. is it documented by microsoft in some place that out-of-proc COM is not supported for registration free activiatation? I searched but couldn't get any information on this.

Comment: I don't have documentation links, but from what i know there is no regfreecom support for out-of-proc servers.

Comment: I found the link here which says out-of-proc is not supported and only dlls are supported. link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx#S4;
search tag "The limitations of Reg-Free COM"